# Sending luggage from Germany to the USA

Tags: usa, luggage, germany

I recently traveled via Asia to the US, only bringing necessities in my backpack. Now we left  ~50kg luggage in Germany and would like to send that over.

DHL offers a luggage service which is like 100€ for 30kg, but I fear that only works if I send it in a suitcase. It's all packed up in cardboard boxes, though they contain suitcases and mostly clothing items.

I cannot find any information on their site if this might be a problem or  not, and I cannot seem to call them (their only means of contact...)

Would this service work for my purpose, or might there be a better way of sending it?
Customs shouldnt be a problem I hope, its all regular stuff you would find in any suitcase.

Comment: DHL can also ship items which are in cardboard boxes! Indeed, that is how most of their packages are packaged!

Comment: @MichaelHampton But the service I'm referring is meant for luggage, not regular shipping. I don't want to spend 210 bucks, just to find out that I cannot send cardboard boxes with that service

Comment: Strange, I can't find this service at all. The only DHL luggage service I can find ships only [domestically](https://www.dhl.de/en/privatkunden/pakete-versenden/deutschlandweit-versenden/reisegepaeck.html) in Germany. What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking in terms of luggage. **Think in terms of *packages***.

UPS, FedEx, DHL and the various national post offices each have a mainline business of shipping things, predominantly in cardboard boxes.  They have rules for shipping durable things which are not in cardboard boxes, e.g. Automobile tires, steel sections, etc.

They also have weight limits in the 20-30kg range, with surcharges above that, because OSHA and other nations' rules require special handling to reduce worker injury.

So rearrange your packages to be within their limits, to discard/donate/sell that which does not need to be shipped, and to segregate things for purposes of Customs, e.g. "All things purchased in USA". Items which require a duty be paid on them, should best be taken with you on your airline flight, and paid at the Customs desk.